How to get SQL queries that pull data for each report from Tableau Server
I am trying to extract all SQL queries (data sources for each report) for all reports from the tableau server. Would Tableau server log files have the queries? Or can I get the queries by connecting to Tableau server through API in Python?
Thank you.

Please edit your question and provide more details to further define your problem and how the documentation did not provide the information that you need. You're use of the term "queries" is not clear -- do you mean data sources? If so, what exactly are you trying to do that isn't specified in the documentation?

@devlincarnate I am trying to get SQL queries for data sources for each report in tableau server. I could not figure out what is the best way to do it. API or logs.

The documentation shows how to get a list of all data sources, and then how to do various things like download or get the metadata or whatever from a single data source.  You would need to implement the logic to get the list, and then loop over each data source.  There is no method to "get the SQL queries".

For embedded data sources, the .twb workbook file has the query in it.  So maybe look at the API documentation for downloading or querying workbooks, not data sources. Then parse the XML to get the query.  I'm not sure where the query is when the data source is an extract / not embedded in the workbook.

This is available in the metadata api. Which is a GraphQL based API. https://help.tableau.com/current/api/metadata_api/en-us/index.html
